# Почему BeautifulSoup возращает [ ]?

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

[image: в чём причина, и как это исправить?]

```py
def parsing():
    print("Парcинг...")
    pars_req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(pars_req.status_code)
    html = pars_req.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    id = soup.find('div').find_all('id')

    print(id)
```

В чём причина? И как это исправить?

Comment: Потому что тега id не существует, наверное?

Comment: Как не существует? Выше изображение есть где тег id ="thread"

Comment: Это не тег, а атрибут

Comment: окей, как тогда найти все элементы по атрибуту id?

Comment: "найти все элементы по атрибуту id?" soup.find_all(id=True)

Comment: неправильно сформулировал, нужно найти все элементы по атрибуту id cо значением thread

Comment: import re soup.find_all('div', id=re.compile("thread"))

Comment: Как сделать так что бы выводилось то что именно в id находится?

Comment: Поставить квадратные скобки и аттрибут указать, так получите значение, например `find("div")["id"]`

Answer (score 0):

В данной строке вы находите все элементы с тегом `id`. Тег - это элемент html, к примеру `<div></div>`.

```py
id = soup.find('div').find_all('id')  # Вы собираете все теги id
```

В Вашем случае Вам нужно забирать с атрибутом `id`. Делается это так:

```py
id = soup.find('div').find_all('div', {"id": "Нужный id"})
```

Comment: не помогло, bs всё равно возращает [ ]

Comment: Проверьте, что возвращает `soup.find('div')`. Может там проблема

Comment: div возращает такое:https://imgur.com/GOGud81

Comment: Не проще забирать дивы по классу?

Comment: bs всё равно возращает [ ] даже если я использую классы вместо айди

Comment: `elements = soup.find_all('div', class_='discussionListItem')`

Comment: Как сделать так что бы выводилось то что именно в id находится, а не весь html код?

Comment: `id[0]['id']`. Получает первый элемент и обращаемся к айдишнику